# How do I make a conditional installer to find or install SQL Server on local or networked machine?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-installer, custom-action

I have written an application that uses a SQL Server database.

I've been using SQL Server Express on my local PC. The app works fine on my PC, so now I'm trying to distribute it.

Most of our customers will be fine with Express on their local machines.

Some of our larger customers may have several employees accessing the same database, so it will need to reside on a server.

How can I make my installer do the following:

1. Ask the user if they want to use a local or network database.
2. Search the PC/network for SQLServer running services and allow them to select one.
3. If not present, install SQL Server Express on their local, or networked machine.

I've read about "custom actions", but they only run after an app's installation has finished, but if I've set SQL Server Express as a "prerequisite", then it gets automatically installed before my custom action gets a chance to run.

I'm using VS2010 (employer requirement), C# / .Net 3.5

Any specific or general advice is appreciated. Am I even using the right approach here?

Comment: Can you push back on the requirements?   I think asking the user to configure the hostname and db instance without presenting a list isn't too much to ask.  You're also getting complicated installing SQL Server Express on a remote machine.

Comment: I think you should check out this page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/k3bb4tfd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx .

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write a bootstrap application that checks for and, if necessary, resolves the SQL server prerequisite before launching your installer. Obviously, your bootstrap app will be checking the registry for certain keys, but I don't know what those are off hand. Someone else will have to provide you the details there.

Your MSI should have a custom action that is run on install, repair or upgrade that checks for the existence of some form of SQL server and, if it isn't there, tells the user to launch the .EXE (your bootstrap app) and then exits. Alternatively, if you don't mind some fiddly work to get it done, you could have your MSI launch the .EXE instead of bringing up a message box in that case.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll look into bootstrap applications.